# Redux child not updating parent component state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I think I am missing something crucial here. I want the App component to register different children based on the states value. When the button from UserType is clicked, nothing happens. I can see via debugging that the reducer is returning the state with the updated step. But i guess App is not registering the state change?

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { UPDATE_STEP, INIT } from '../actions';

const INITIAL_STATE = { step : 1 };

function testReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action){
    console.log('reducing the actions');
    console.debug('Working with', action.type);

    switch(action.type) {
        case UPDATE_STEP:
            return {
                ...state,
                step : state.step + 1
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    test : testReducer
});

export default rootReducer;
```

actions/index.js

```
export const UPDATE_STEP = 'UPDATE_STEP';

export function updateStep(step) {
    return {
        type : UPDATE_STEP,
        step
    };
}
```

components/user-type.js

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { updateStep } from '../actions';

class UserType extends React.Component {

    onClick() {
        this.props.updateStep(2);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hai</p>
                <button onClick={ this.onClick.bind(this) }>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default connect(null, { updateStep })(UserType);
```

components/app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import UserType from './user-type';
import Test from './test';

class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
        switch(this.props.page) {
            case 1:
                return <UserType />;
            case 2:
                return <Test />;
            default:
                return <UserType />;
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { step : state.test.step };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps. null)(App);
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import App from './components/app';
import reducers from './reducers';

let store = createStore(reducers);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={ store }>
        <App />
    </Provider>
, document.querySelector('#view-container'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two problems in your code, both in components/app.js

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps. null)(App);
```

There is a "." instead of a "," which simply passes over undefined.

Second thing is your switch statement

```
switch(this.props.page) {...}
```

but you map your redux-store to the prob `step`

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { step : state.test.step };
};
```

So you will always end up in the default case here. So you should use `switch(this.props.step)` instead.

Comment: God damn typos. Thank you sir